# NSDictionary: validationhash fails to validate (Secure-NSUserDefaults)

Tags: ios, objective-c, hash, md5, nsuserdefaults

I am using this helper class: [Secure-NSUserDefaults](https://github.com/matthiasplappert/Secure-NSUserDefaults)

I'm running into a problem where the *validationhash* differs from the stored hash for a NSDictionary when I modify the latter and try saving it again.

Here is my code:

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
BOOL valid = NO;
NSDictionary * modDict = [defaults secureDictionaryForKey:aKey valid:&valid];
if (!valid) {
    //handle
}
for (NSString * modKey in modDict) {
        NSMutableArray * modArray = [[modDict objectForKey:modKey] mutableCopy];
        NSString * newValue = @"newValue";
        [modArray replaceObjectAtIndex:0 withObject:newValue];
        NSMutableDictionary *newModDict = [modDict mutableCopy];
        [newModDict setObject:modArray forKey:modKey];
        [defaults setSecureObject:newModDict forKey:aKey];
        [defaults synchronize];
}
```

When I run this code **once**, kill the app, and start it again, all works as it should, and the *validationhash* matches. It always matches correctly on the first run, in fact. In other words: my code saves out the secure dictionary and the *hash* matches on the subsequent app run just fine (once).

BUT - if I run the **same code** a second time **without** killing the app between runs, the *validationhash* is different, and the *&valid* check fails.

I was able to trace down the problem to this line:

```
[newModDict setObject:modArray forKey:modKey];
```

If I comment it out, it works fine all the time, but then of course, the modification I am trying to make isn't made at all, I simply copy the Dictionary "as is".

I'm struggling to figure out what I am doing wrong or how to modify and re-save the NSDictionary so that the *hash* matches.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LOL! Funny how sometimes writing down a question in a concise way triggers new ideas. It just occurred to me what I had to do, and just now solved it like this:

```
[newModDict setObject:[modArray copy] forKey:modKey];
```

i.e. I had to make the edited `NSArray` non-mutable first.

Maybe someone will benefit from the answer. I'm too embarrassed to mention how long I worked on this last night.